# Why in the program "Prolog for eight puzzle" user slago uses the command: time(ids) I can't undestand why he uses this command

Tags: prolog

?- time(ids). What is the meaning of this command? What is the meaning of time?

I am expecting to undestand in Slago's 8-Puzzle proigram the menaing of command ?- time(ids). during execution

Comment: Is using https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=time/1

Answer (score 1):

`?- time(...).` prints this at the end of slago's output:

```
% 97,719,612 inferences, 40.344 CPU in 40.991 seconds (98% CPU, 2422175 Lips)
```

It's the runtime of the solution in Prolog logical inferences and CPU use in seconds. Good for quick comparisons to see if changes to the code speed it up or slow it down, and good for posting here to show people roughly how long the code takes to search for a solution.